# How do I define these undefine android kernel modules in android 10?

Tags: android-source, android-module

I am trying to build hybris boot using some tried and true forked lineage os 17.1 source for nexus 10. Originally I got this error:

```
error: packages/services/Telecomm/Android.bp:28:1: "TelecomUnitTests" depends on undefined module "SettingsLibDefaults"
19:58:34 soong bootstrap failed with: exit status 1
```

Fine then, go to android bp and remove that line since I don't need telecomms anyway at this moment (there is no cellular nexus 10 and the sailfish os rootfs won't interact with any telephony frameworks anyway).

now I get a TON of errors that are similar:

```
error: prebuilts/sdk/current/extras/app-toolkit/Android.bp:276:1: "android-arch-persistence-db" depends on undefined module "framework-res"
error: external/setupdesign/Android.bp:5:1: "setupdesign" depends on undefined module "framework-res"
error: frameworks/opt/net/wifi/service/proto/Android.bp:15:1: "wifi_service_proto" depends on undefined module "ext"
error: frameworks/opt/net/wifi/service/proto/Android.bp:15:1: "wifi_service_proto" depends on undefined module "framework"
error: frameworks/opt/net/wifi/service/proto/Android.bp:15:1: "wifi_service_proto" depends on undefined module "updatable_media_stubs"
error: prebuilts/sdk/current/support/Android.bp:358:1: "android-support-heifwriter" depends on undefined module "framework-res"
error: prebuilts/sdk/current/androidx/Android.bp:18:1: "androidx.activity_activity" depends on undefined module "framework-res"
error: prebuilts/sdk/current/androidx/Android.bp:994:1: "androidx.lifecycle_lifecycle-livedata-nodeps" depends on undefined module "framework-res"
error: cts/tests/tests/uirendering/Android.bp:15:1: "CtsUiRenderingTestCases" depends on undefined module "ext"
error: cts/tests/tests/uirendering/Android.bp:15:1: "CtsUiRenderingTestCases" depends on undefined module "framework"
error: cts/tests/tests/uirendering/Android.bp:15:1: "CtsUiRenderingTestCases" depends on undefined module "updatable_media_stubs"
error: cts/tests/tests/uirendering/Android.bp:15:1: "CtsUiRenderingTestCases" depends on undefined module "android.test.runner.stubs"
error: cts/tests/tests/uirendering/Android.bp:15:1: "CtsUiRenderingTestCases" depends on undefined module "framework-res"
error: frameworks/opt/chips/Android.bp:15:1: "libchips" depends on undefined module "framework-res"
error: frameworks/av/media/libmediaplayer2/nuplayer2/Android.bp:1:1: "libstagefright_nuplayer2" depends on undefined module "libmediaplayer2-protos"
error: bootable/recovery/updater_sample/tests/Android.bp:15:1: "SystemUpdaterSampleTests" depends on undefined module "android.test.base.stubs"
error: bootable/recovery/updater_sample/tests/Android.bp:15:1: "SystemUpdaterSampleTests" depends on undefined module "android.test.runner.stubs"
error: bootable/recovery/updater_sample/tests/Android.bp:15:1: "SystemUpdaterSampleTests" depends on undefined module "framework-res"
error: packages/services/Car/EncryptionRunner/Android.bp:32:1: "EncryptionRunnerTest" depends on undefined module "ext"
error: packages/services/Car/EncryptionRunner/Android.bp:32:1: "EncryptionRunnerTest" depends on undefined module "framework"
error: packages/services/Car/EncryptionRunner/Android.bp:32:1: "EncryptionRunnerTest" depends on undefined module "updatable_media_stubs"
error: packages/services/Car/EncryptionRunner/Android.bp:32:1: "EncryptionRunnerTest" depends on undefined module "android.test.base"
error: packages/services/Car/EncryptionRunner/Android.bp:32:1: "EncryptionRunnerTest" depends on undefined module "android.test.runner"
error: packages/services/Car/EncryptionRunner/Android.bp:32:1: "EncryptionRunnerTest" depends on undefined module "framework-res"
error: prebuilts/misc/common/androidx-test/Android.bp:301:1: "androidx.test.uiautomator-nodeps" depends on undefined module "framework-res"
error: packages/inputmethods/LeanbackIME/Android.bp:4:1: "LeanbackIME" depends on undefined module "framework-res"
error: external/libchrome/Android.bp:948:1: "android.mojo" depends on undefined module "ext"
error: external/libchrome/Android.bp:948:1: "android.mojo" depends on undefined module "framework"
error: external/libchrome/Android.bp:948:1: "android.mojo" depends on undefined module "updatable_media_stubs"
error: prebuilts/misc/common/androidx-test/Android.bp:276:1: "androidx.test.runner-nodeps" depends on undefined module "framework-res"
error: prebuilts/sdk/current/androidx/Android.bp:1126:1: "androidx.loader_loader" depends on undefined module "framework-res"
error: external/libbackup/Android.bp:1:1: "libbackup" depends on undefined module "framework-res"
error: packages/providers/BookmarkProvider/Android.bp:15:1: "BookmarkProvider" depends on undefined module "ext"
error: packages/providers/BookmarkProvider/Android.bp:15:1: "BookmarkProvider" depends on undefined module "framework"
error: packages/providers/BookmarkProvider/Android.bp:15:1: "BookmarkProvider" depends on undefined module "updatable_media_stubs"
error: packages/providers/BookmarkProvider/Android.bp:15:1: "BookmarkProvider" depends on undefined module "framework-res"
error: prebuilts/sdk/current/androidx/Android.bp:310:1: "androidx.cardview_cardview" depends on undefined module "framework-res"
error: cts/tests/tests/packageinstaller/atomicinstall/Android.bp:45:1: "AtomicInstallTestAppAv1" depends on undefined module "ext"
error: cts/tests/tests/packageinstaller/atomicinstall/Android.bp:45:1: "AtomicInstallTestAppAv1" depends on undefined module "framework"
error: cts/tests/tests/packageinstaller/atomicinstall/Android.bp:45:1: "AtomicInstallTestAppAv1" depends on undefined module "updatable_media_stubs"
error: cts/tests/tests/packageinstaller/atomicinstall/Android.bp:45:1: "AtomicInstallTestAppAv1" depends on undefined module "framework-res"
error: platform_testing/libraries/car-helpers/multiuser-helper/Android.bp:16:1: "multi-user-helper" depends on undefined module "ext"
error: platform_testing/libraries/car-helpers/multiuser-helper/Android.bp:16:1: "multi-user-helper" depends on undefined module "framework"
error: platform_testing/libraries/car-helpers/multiuser-helper/Android.bp:16:1: "multi-user-helper" depends on undefined module "updatable_media_stubs"
error: cts/hostsidetests/appsecurity/test-apps/ReviewPermissionHelper/Android.bp:15:1: "ReviewPermissionHelper" depends on undefined module "ext"
error: cts/hostsidetests/appsecurity/test-apps/ReviewPermissionHelper/Android.bp:15:1: "ReviewPermissionHelper" depends on undefined module "framework"
error: cts/hostsidetests/appsecurity/test-apps/ReviewPermissionHelper/Android.bp:15:1: "ReviewPermissionHelper" depends on undefined module "updatable_media_stubs"
error: cts/hostsidetests/appsecurity/test-apps/ReviewPermissionHelper/Android.bp:15:1: "ReviewPermissionHelper" depends on undefined module "framework-res"
error: prebuilts/sdk/current/support/Android.bp:940:1: "android-support-dynamic-animation" depends on undefined module "framework-res"
error: prebuilts/sdk/current/support/Android.bp:653:1: "android-support-recommendation" depends on undefined module "framework-res"
error: vendor/nxp/opensource/commonsys/external/libnfc-nci/src/Android.bp:1:1: "libnqnfc-nci" depends on undefined module "libstatslog"
error: platform_testing/utils/permissions/Android.bp:25:1: "PermissionUtils" depends on undefined module "ext"
error: platform_testing/utils/permissions/Android.bp:25:1: "PermissionUtils" depends on undefined module "framework"
error: platform_testing/utils/permissions/Android.bp:25:1: "PermissionUtils" depends on undefined module "updatable_media_stubs"
error: platform_testing/utils/permissions/Android.bp:25:1: "PermissionUtils" depends on undefined module "framework-res"
error: prebuilts/sdk/current/androidx-legacy/Android.bp:19:1: "androidx.legacy_legacy-preference-v14" depends on undefined module "framework-res"
error: prebuilts/sdk/current/androidx/Android.bp:1363:1: "androidx.percentlayout_percentlayout-nodeps" depends on undefined module "framework-res"
error: prebuilts/misc/common/androidx-test/Android.bp:70:1: "androidx.test.espresso.core" depends on undefined module "framework-res"
error: prebuilts/sdk/current/support/Android.bp:379:1: "android-support-interpolator" depends on undefined module "framework-res"
error: frameworks/ex/framesequence/jni/Android.bp:17:1: "libframesequence" depends on undefined module "libjnigraphics.ndk.16"
error: prebuilts/sdk/current/androidx/Android.bp:1439:1: "androidx.recommendation_recommendation-nodeps" depends on undefined module "framework-res"
error: prebuilts/misc/common/androidx-test/Android.bp:220:1: "androidx.test.janktesthelper" depends on undefined module "framework-res"
error: packages/screensavers/Basic/Android.bp:1:1: "BasicDreams" depends on undefined module "ext"
error: packages/screensavers/Basic/Android.bp:1:1: "BasicDreams" depends on undefined module "framework"
error: packages/screensavers/Basic/Android.bp:1:1: "BasicDreams" depends on undefined module "updatable_media_stubs"
error: packages/screensavers/Basic/Android.bp:1:1: "BasicDreams" depends on undefined module "framework-res"
error: prebuilts/misc/common/androidx-test/Android.bp:286:1: "androidx.test.runner" depends on undefined module "framework-res"
error: prebuilts/sdk/current/support/Android.bp:245:1: "android-support-customview" depends on undefined module "framework-res"
error: packages/providers/MediaProvider/tests/Android.bp:1:1: "MediaProviderTests" depends on undefined module "ext"
error: packages/providers/MediaProvider/tests/Android.bp:1:1: "MediaProviderTests" depends on undefined module "framework"
error: packages/providers/MediaProvider/tests/Android.bp:1:1: "MediaProviderTests" depends on undefined module "updatable_media_stubs"
error: packages/providers/MediaProvider/tests/Android.bp:1:1: "MediaProviderTests" depends on undefined module "android.test.base"
error: packages/providers/MediaProvider/tests/Android.bp:1:1: "MediaProviderTests" depends on undefined module "android.test.mock"
error: packages/providers/MediaProvider/tests/Android.bp:1:1: "MediaProviderTests" depends on undefined module "android.test.runner"
error: packages/providers/MediaProvider/tests/Android.bp:1:1: "MediaProviderTests" depends on undefined module "framework-res"
error: platform_testing/tests/example/devcodelab/Android.bp:15:1: "DevCodelabTest" depends on undefined module "ext"
error: platform_testing/tests/example/devcodelab/Android.bp:15:1: "DevCodelabTest" depends on undefined module "framework"
error: platform_testing/tests/example/devcodelab/Android.bp:15:1: "DevCodelabTest" depends on undefined module "updatable_media_stubs"
error: platform_testing/tests/example/devcodelab/Android.bp:15:1: "DevCodelabTest" depends on undefined module "framework-res"
error: packages/providers/CalendarProvider/Android.bp:17:1: "CalendarProvider" depends on undefined module "ext"
error: packages/providers/CalendarProvider/Android.bp:17:1: "CalendarProvider" depends on undefined module "framework"
error: packages/providers/CalendarProvider/Android.bp:17:1: "CalendarProvider" depends on undefined module "updatable_media_stubs"
error: packages/providers/CalendarProvider/Android.bp:17:1: "CalendarProvider" depends on undefined module "framework-res"
error: prebuilts/sdk/current/androidx/Android.bp:646:1: "androidx.fragment_fragment" depends on undefined module "framework-res"
error: prebuilts/sdk/current/support/Android.bp:954:1: "android-support-emoji-appcompat-nodeps" depends on undefined module "framework-res"
error: prebuilts/sdk/current/androidx/Android.bp:1800:1: "androidx.swiperefreshlayout_swiperefreshlayout" depends on undefined module "framework-res"
error: prebuilts/sdk/current/support/Android.bp:1254:1: "android-support-viewpager" depends on undefined module "framework-res"
error: prebuilts/sdk/current/support/Android.bp:978:1: "android-support-emoji-bundled-nodeps" depends on undefined module "framework-res"
error: prebuilts/sdk/current/androidx/Android.bp:235:1: "androidx.car_car-cluster-nodeps" depends on undefined module "framework-res"
error: platform_testing/tests/functional/testapks/permissiontestappmv1/Android.bp:1:1: "PermissionTestAppMV1" depends on undefined module "ext"
error: platform_testing/tests/functional/testapks/permissiontestappmv1/Android.bp:1:1: "PermissionTestAppMV1" depends on undefined module "framework"
error: platform_testing/tests/functional/testapks/permissiontestappmv1/Android.bp:1:1: "PermissionTestAppMV1" depends on undefined module "updatable_media_stubs"
error: platform_testing/tests/functional/testapks/permissiontestappmv1/Android.bp:1:1: "PermissionTestAppMV1" depends on undefined module "framework-res"
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

`#### failed to build some targets (54 seconds) ####`

Where do I define these modules? I poked around in board config but I don't know where they are importing them from. Am I just missing some source?

Comment: Please, do not use single-backtick (`\``) for wrap **multiline** code or log. This formatting doesn't preserve newlines. Instead, use triple-backtick (`\`\`\``) wrapping or indent all lines with a 4 spaces (using `Ctrl+K` or `{}` button).